# Cannot filter on contact subtype in Drupal8 views

Tags: contacts, drupal-views, drupal-8

I don't know the depth of CiviCRM's official commitment to Drupal 8 yet, but I've followed the instructions posted [here](https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/how-install-civicrm-drupal-8-and-why-choose-it-over-pure-drupal-crm) for setting it up.

After creating a contact subtype of "Committee" and creating a Drupal view for "CiviCRM Contacts", I attempted to filter on the Committee subtype.  When saving, I got a raw server error displayed:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

Checking the Apache logs, I saw:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The configuration property display.default.display_options.filters.contact_sub_type.value.Committee doesn't exist." at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php line 76
```

This seems to imply that the CiviCRM Views integration isn't providing something that the Views module wants in order to validate the filter value.

Anyone have any suggestions for next steps?  Is CiviCRM's dev team developing for Drupal 8 and do they want related bug reports?

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to join https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/drupal which is where some active discussion about D8 is happening.

Including this [update](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/jz96ujohjffsixbdbt8s89tsmy) about webform integration

Comment: Also note that while CiviCRM has a 'core team' a lot of work is done by the community, so while reporting bugs is useful, finding a way to contribute in some way can increase the speed with which bugs get resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the discussion forum.  I was at a loss for where to refer.  I'm game for getting involved in coding, pull requests, etc., but right now half the battle is just figuring out where the code worth working on might be.

Comment: And don't get me started on the state of Drupal8 documentation and project support.  It's really chaotic right now.

Comment: It will be great if you can help improve the community documentation for this. Not sure what you mean by 'project support'. there isn't a team of paid 'support workers'. we are mostly other folk using civi voluntarily or as part of our business who opt to try and help out others in the hope that strengthens the community and the project

Comment: I should have been more clear.  By project support, I meant module support for Drupal8 as opposed to Drupal7.  As it stands, IMO Drupal8 is only barely over the line of being production capable and only for the most basic of sites.  Despite the improvements to core feature completeness, core still lacks many important features, and many of the modules that support them are still in dev status.

Comment: We know that civicrm is not fully featured for D8 yet. But bit by bit the community does its best to add features, but without a major donor/sponsor/client it happens as and when folk can put in the effort. There is now some roadmap for webform per this https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/jz96ujohjffsixbdbt8s89tsmy - will be great if you can help move the project along.

Comment: And, again I was unclear:  My beef is primarily with the state of D8 itself, not with Civi.  It's been made clear by the team that Civi is not fully D8 compatible and I'm not knocking the progress -- it's excellent to be moving that way.  D8 itself, on the other hand, is disorganized, confusing, and incomplete for all but the most basic of sites -- even installing D8 is a nightmare of multiple options and confusing tutorials and official documentation, which, if you follow the official instructions, can even result in an installation that doesn't support automatic updates. Very disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this report.

You can report issues at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues.

While CiviCRM works under Drupal 8 fine in terms of independent CiviCRM functionality, the support for various integrations into Drupal 8 is still a work in progress. Coleman with support from David Snopek and Will put out a prototype / mockup of  D8 webform civicrm May 25 2018.  There is going to be a Make It Happen fundraising effort and I'm sure that developer resources and effort will be appreciated.

For view support the plan is to implement a D8 version of entity civicrm module, and then leverage D8 Views support for entities. We at JMA recently pushed some changes to improve D8 entity civicrm support for contacts, but weren't using subtypes like you are. So it may or may not work when using entities. We are also ensuring there is good  support for events in views via entities, and starting to help @jackrabbithanna with improvements to earlier Drupal versions of his entity civicrm module.

Feel free to contact me at joe dot murray at jmaconsulting dot biz if you'd like us to get specific D8 integration issues working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the orientation.  Knowing the strategy is very helpful.  We (my company) are very open to getting involved at the coding/documentation level, so we'll check into how we can contribute effectively.  I'll start by logging what I found in the issue tracker.

Comment: Note I just editted to include new status of webform civicrm integration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity/)? It seems to work when using that module. Tested on CiviCRM 5.14 and Drupal 8.6.

[image: CiviCRM View with CiviCRM Entity]